# How to use HTTPContext to get a web address in C#

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I have been looking for a way to get the web address of websites currently open in a browser. I have come across lots of posts saying to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` or similar.

However from what I have read, `HttpContext` should be used once a http request has been made. How would I detect when this has happened since currently it always returns a null?

Or is there another way to do get web addresses currently being used?

Edit:

I am using Windows Forms. The overall aim is to get web address of pages the user has accessed from a form.

Thanks

Comment: Have checked `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName` and `HttpContext.Current.Request,UserHostAddress` properties?

Comment: What is your application? If you are running in the context of web-application, then HttpContext should always exist. If you don't, then this question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If it does not use HttpContext, maybe it is a WCF, which has an equivalent context. You are missing information of your app

Comment: He says he's talking about pages open in a browser's tabs. This means that he must run in the context of the browser - that is, create a Browser Extension. This will be different for each browser.

Comment: I have edited my question, to provide a bit more context, hopefully clear some bits up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the web address of a website currently open in the user's browser?
If so, I don't think the mentioned method will work.

Or do you want to get the web address of a page that is part of your application and is being accessed by the user?
If so, you can access this information in your controller method. The URI information is available at [Request.RequestedUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.request?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I believe this is valid for both [WebApi controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [MVC Controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Also, I'm assuming you are working with ASP.NET Core. Please tell if using .NET Framework.

Comment: Of the addresses already in my browser. The overall aim is to have the application open in the background and when the user uses a browser, have the application get the web addresses they have accessed. I am using .Net for windows form